# ical4j causes Java Heap Size Error on Android Project

Tags: java, icalendar

i'm trying to use a new version of ical4j in my android project because old versions doesn't work.

But when i try to run my application takes so much time to compile... and at last i get an error saying

```
 "Java Heap Size" .
```

And that occours when eclipse is compiling a class named "groovyjarjars" included on ical4j.

this is very frustrating because this is the only library that parses ics files (ical) and it's just giving problems since i updated the ADT Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Remove the groovy jar,all that is necessary is backport-util.concurrent, ical4j and commons-lang this works for me.